# Unable to generate html using theme_table in block view

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I have created a block_view, In that block I want to show dynamic table.

I have written following code.

```
$table_headers = array(t('User'), t('Relation'),t('Period') );
foreach ($result as $row) {
            $table_rows[] = array(
            $row->name,
            $row->relation,
            $row->period_from,
           );
         }
 dpm($table_rows);
```

In above `$table_rows` array, I am getting following elements

[image]

If I am using

```
$table_html = theme_table($table_headers,$table_rows);
$block['content'] = $table_html;
```

then getting following error on page

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

If I used

```
$table_html = theme('table',$table_headers,$table_rows);
dpm($table_html); 
$block['content'] = $table_html;
```

I am getting following html on page

[image]

Please suggest were I made mistake and what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is how you pass the parameters to the theme hook. You should use the following code.

```
$block['content'] = theme('table', array('header' => $table_headers, 'rows' => $table_rows));
```

In Drupal 7, theme hooks receive their parameters in an array.

You could also use the following code, since on Drupal 7 you can directly use a render array.

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $table_headers,
  '#rows' => $table_rows
);
```

If a module modified the *table* theme hook, and you don't understand which variables the modified version uses, or in general, if you don't know which variables are used from a theme hook, you can print the value returned from [`theme_get_registry()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_get_registry/7.x) to check that.
For example, in my test site, `drush ev "\$hooks = theme_get_registry(); var_export(\$hooks['table']);"` prints me the following.

```
array (
  'variables' => array(
    'header' => NULL,
    'rows' => NULL,
    'attributes' => array(),
    'caption' => NULL,
    'colgroups' => array(),
    'sticky' => true,
    'empty' => '',
  ),
  'type' => 'module',
  'theme path' => 'modules/system',
  'function' => 'theme_table',
)
```

Comment: this is not in [drupal's theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7.x), can you suggest me other documentation ?

Comment: I will update the answer later.

Comment: I suggested a method to find out which variables are used from a theme hook.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Drupal 7, and assuming `$table_rows` and `$table_headers` contain valid data, this is what you need:

```
$block['content'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#rows' => $table_rows,
  '#header' => $table_headers,
  '#empty' => 'Nothing to see here...',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming drupal 7, and assuming $table_headers and $table_rows have correct data.

```
$table_headers = array(t('User'), t('Relation'),t('Period') );
foreach ($result as $row) {
            $table_rows[] = array(
            $row->name,
            $row->relation,
            $row->period_from,
           );
         }

$output = theme('table', array('header' => $table_headers, 'rows'=> $table_rows));
```